# Make certain text in outlook incoming e-mails into links?

Tags: php, vbscript, outlook

I'd like to do some operations on incoming e-mails. Namely transform all 6 digit numbers into links which lead to a url based on the number.

I don't want to open a huge can of worms, in terms of APIs or languages besides PHP, this isn't that much of a timesaver, but it would be nice. Anyone done anything like this? Just looking to get pointed in the right direction !

Comment: I'm confused, do you need PHP code or VBScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to find your numbers and replace them with your links. Since I do not know your link structure, I made one up.

Here is a simple example:

```
$str = "Testing 385758 String";
preg_replace( '/(\d{6})/', '<a href="www.example.com/index.php?number=$1">$1</a>', $str);
```

This will turn `$str` into:

```
Testing <a href="www.example.com/index.php?number=385758">385758</a> String
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KIXKNj)